# Is there a general way to detect file write errors with c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, boost, io, filesystems

I have an application that writes several files depending on the specific config. Sometimes we use the normal std:ostream, sometimes we write with opencv, or with boost.

For std:ostream rdstate() function. 
In my opinion the best solution would be, if I could use some general method (e.g. from the os), that works for each mechanism.
Is there something like this?

If not, can anyone point me to documentation about checks similar to rdstate()?
Thanks

Update:
I write the files with these functions:
OpenCV: `cv::VideoWriter << image`
boost: `boost::iostreams::file_sink->write`

I found a way to check the written data for the bosst case. The `write` function returns the number of written bytes, and I can compare this to the expected bytes. 
For the openCV case I used `GetFileAttributesEx` the determine the filesize and check if that increases.
Is that a good way?

Comment: Are you looking for a method that works on all operating systems?

Comment: No, I just need windows

Comment: A general way of checking for errors is to call GetLastError().

Comment: @Ian that's way out of context.

Comment: @Valerie Could you, please, elaborate on how specifically you "write with opencv, or with boost"?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post an example for all different kind of writes you have. Then, a solution could probably be creating a macro to wrap them around.

Comment: Added some more info as edit to the post

Comment: I would guess `cv::VideoWriter` throws in case of writing failure, I'll check the source code tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying operating system call that writes to a file returns an error indication, I would expect `std::ostream` to end up in a `fail()` state.

You just have to be diligent about checking the status of the `std::ostream`, including after an explicit `close()`, since a write error could be encountered writing out the final bits of buffered data.

Comment: You espect `std::ostream` to be in a failed status also after a failed boost or opencv write?

Comment: I have no knowledge of either framework, so I cannot answer that.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt help me, because as far as I know neither opencv nor boost use std::ostreams

Comment: Then why is the question referring to std::ostream?